# differential Eq, how do I make it Exact? (using an integrating factor?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

$$ye^xdx-(4y+3e^x)dy=0$$

$$(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}) * \frac{1}{M}$$
$$e^{\int(4/y)}=y^4 $$

- when multiplying $$y^4$$ though the problem still does not become exact?

[attempt (cant find my error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci7ep.png)
, this will not make it exact...?
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the curly line with an arrow on the end mean?

Comment: o sorry , its just means the "thing" on the left is this... that formula becomes this

Comment: I think that is normally written as "$=$".

Comment: denominator should be $-M$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
Denominator should be $−M$, then the integrating factor is
$$\dfrac{1}{y^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ye^xdx-(4y+3e^x)dy=0$$
$$Pdx+Qdy=0$$

Facteur integrating is
$$\ln ( \mu)=-\int \frac 1 P (\partial_y P-\partial_x Q)dy=-\int \frac {4}y=-4\ln y$$
$$\implies \mu =y^{-4}$$
multiply by $1/y^4$
$$\implies \frac {e^x}{y^3}dx-(\frac 4{y^3}+3\frac {e^x}{y^4})dy=0$$
Now it's exact
$$\partial_y(\frac {e^x}{y^3})=\partial_x(-\frac 4{y^3}-3\frac {e^x}{y^4})$$